# Sum of Series Problem in Complex Analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis

How can i solve this sum of series using complex analysis?

$$1-\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{4^2}+...=...$$

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

Why complex analysis? Assuming we know

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6}=S:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}=\frac{1}{4}S+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}\implies$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}=\frac{3}{4}S=\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ldots$$

Last hint: split your series in two, using each converges absolutely...